# Assign fill value to variable if it does not equal to certain values

Tags: gfortran, fortran95

I am not pro in Fortran95, but I am writing a code in it and I found that I want to mask the array values with -9999, if it does not have certain values.

Example: I have an array 'X' has values vary from 0 to 32768, and I want to mask the values of the array, if 'X' value is not equal to 0,1,2,16 or 18. I solved it with the following syntax:

```
if (X.eq.0.or.X.eq.1.or.X.eq.2.or.X.eq.16.or.X.eq.18) then
    X=X
else
    X=-9999
end if
```

But there any other way to mask array values in FORTRAN 95?

Comment: You say you "have an array `X`", but your code treats `X` as a scalar.

Answer (score 2):

There is the `where` statement that can mask the array, but given the logical you have shown its a bit ugly

```
where (.not.(X==0 || X==1 || X==2 || X==16 || X==18)) x = -9999
```

Comment: you are right that my logic is a bit ugly and thank you for your answer. I tried your solution, but it gives me a parenthesis error.

Answer (score 1):

For these kinds of problems I find it convenient to define the `.in.` operator, which returns whether or not a scalar is in an array, so:

- `1 .in. [0, 1, 2]` returns `.true.`
- `3 .in. [0, 1, 2]` returns `.false.`
- `[1, 3] .in. [0, 1, 2]` returns `[.true., .false.]`

This can be defined as

```
module in_module
  implicit none
  
  interface operator(.in.)
    module procedure element_in_list
    module procedure elements_in_list
  end interface
contains
  function element_in_list(lhs, rhs) result(output)
    integer, intent(in) :: lhs
    integer, intent(in) :: rhs(:)
    logical :: output
    
    output = any(lhs==rhs)
  end function
  
  function elements_in_list(lhs, rhs) result(output)
    integer, intent(in) :: lhs(:)
    integer, intent(in) :: rhs(:)
    logical, allocatable :: output(:)
    
    integer :: i
    
    output = [(any(lhs(i)==rhs), i=1, size(lhs))]
  end function
end module
```

With the `.in.` operator defined, then if `X` is an array you can write

```
where (.not. (X .in. [0, 1, 2, 16, 18])) X = -9999
```

which will convert e.g. `X = [4, 5, 1, 3, 16]` to `X = [-9999, -9999, 1, -9999, 16]`.

If you want to simplify things further (as the `where` construct can be quite unwieldy), you can also define the function `filter` which takes an array of logicals and returns the indices of the `.true.` values, e.g. `filter([.false., .true., .true.])` returns `[2, 3]`.

This can be defined as:

```
function filter(input) result(output)
  logical, intent(in) :: input(:)
  integer, allocatable :: output(:)
  
  integer :: i
  
  output = pack([(i, i=1, size(input))], input)
end function
```

And then you can simply write

```
X(filter(.not. (X .in. [0, 1, 2, 16, 18]))) = -9999
```

Comment: This is a nice solution given the number of conditions to match.  After my post, I thought a bit about another solution using a logical array to build the mask.  `msk = .true.; where(any(x == 0)) msk = .false.; where(any(x==1)) mask = .false.; etc.` and then finally `where(msk) x = -9999`.